# 'Bootsrap 4.0.0 stable' causes 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.'

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, bootstrap-4

So far I have been using Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta2 and the plugin jquery-Validate vs. 1.17.0 to validate form data.
That was ok.

Now I went over to 'Bootstrap 4.0.0 stable' and got the following error:

```
jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element idUserNameProvRegister, check the 'remote' method.
    at Function.a.ajaxPrefilter.a.ajax (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at a.validator.remote (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at a.validator.check (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at a.validator.element (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at a.validator.onfocusout (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.b (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at Object.simulate (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
```

The problem seems to arise from this part of code that is needed by the jquery-Validation plugin:

```
  $("#idFormProvRegister").validate({

        rules:{
          UserNameProvRegister: {
                required:       true,
                length_username: true,
                alphanumeric:   true,

                remote: {   
                    url: "ajax/IstUserNameVergeben.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        UserNameProvRegister: function(){
                            return $("#idUserNameProvRegister").val();
                        }
                    }              
                }
          },
  .....
```

I have made no changes to my own code except for these cdns (required for new Bootstrap version):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In both cases ('BS 4.0.0 beta2' as well as 'BS 4.0.0 stable') I used the same jquery version.
Does anybody know how to solve that issue?

Henry

Comment: @Sparky: Thanks for your immediate response.
I had taken the recommended CDNs from the [Getting Started site] (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) and was caught in the trap.
They use the slim version of jquery, not saying that it does not support AJAX. So I exchanged it with jquery.min.js and it worked.
Your comments were very helpful and finally led to the solution.
Thank you very much!
Henry

Comment: Ugh... "slim" does not contain Ajax?  IMO, that's the one thing I'd think all flavors of jQuery should have.  Anyway, you're welcome.  I converted my comments into an answer for the benefit of future readers.  Please accept this answer if you see fit.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky Very useful answer, I am sure many other readers will benefit from it. I'm really happy that there are people like you out there who spent there time to care for other people's problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Some troubleshooting is in order.  Install the un-minified version of the plugin so the error message can be tracked to something readable.
2. The error message contains, *"Exception occurred when checking element `idUserNameProvRegister`, **check the 'remote' method**."* So this should narrow things down quite a bit.
3. You have installed something called jQuery "Slim".  I am pretty sure this is not the full version of jQuery.  (As per OP's comments, "slim" does not support Ajax)
4. Finally, the `data` parameter within `remote` is completely superfluous in this case.  By default, the `remote` method sends the value of the field being validated, so there is no need to specify it.

Comment: You saved my day! So many times the "Slim" version has bitten me in the ass.